# Transfer data to a secured database by POST message and authentication using a servercertificate

Tags: curl, post, soapui, tls1.2, client-certificates

We want to establish a secured connection with our governmental institute that collects laboratory analysis that are performed for the legal determination of the nutrient content.

For this we connection we they have two end points:
Acception-environment: https://acceptatie.webservices.dictu.nl/labws/LabAnalyse 145.12.137.54
Production-environment: https://webservices.dictu.nl/labws/LabAnalyse
They use WS-security 1.1 standard from OASIS, Username Token profile 1.1.

I should use a:

- TLS 1.2. connection
- Send an xml/soap message with header containing username and password.

https://mijn.rvo.nl/documents/20448/1376512/Berichtenboek+LAI+Services.pdf/ae4050ad-a083-4a68-8443-f8e969cdcf8b?t=1574153232177 (Document with information on this, if any translation is required please let me know).

We have ordered the required certificate PKIoverheid Public servercertificate.

Of this I have received a .pem and .key file. I added the .pem to Certmgr.exe in windows 10 also the required CA files:
KPN PKIoverheid server CA 2020; Staat der Nederlanden Server CA 2020 and Staat der Nederlanden EV Root CA

At the side of the government they have installed the public key which was in the .pem certificate; they removed the IP-restriction.

Now we do try to connect to their server and post a SOAP message but so far we have not been able to get this working.

First we tried SOAPUI, but then we run in to the error:
`ERROR:java.net.UnknownHostException: acceptatie.webservices.dictu.nl`

Then we tried to send the message using curl, but somehow I do not manage to get it working.

```
$ curl -k –-cert mestanalyse.wur.nl_20210923.pem –-key mestanalyse.wur.nl.key -cacert 20220113_mestanalyse.wur.nl_onlyroots.cer -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @message-to-rvo.xml https://acceptatie.webservices.dictu.nl/labws/LabAnalyse --trace-ascii logging
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xn---cert-xu3b
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl_20210923.pem
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xn---key-z86a
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl.key
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 20220113_mestanalyse.wur.nl_onlyroots.cer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

According to the governmental institute we try to connect with a certificate with the wrong common name (CN). Namely the CN which is mentioned in my personal client authentication certificate. I guess this indicates that the wrong certificate is send, but somehow I have not been able to solve this. Furthermore, I can't figure out what causes the could not resolve host error.

If you do have any idea what could solve this or help me any further, please let me know.

Kind regards,
Bram

Edit: when I add -v, I do have to remove --trace-ascii as this overrides the -v command. The result:

```
kool035@L0154532 MINGW64 ~
$ curl -v -k –-cert mestanalyse.wur.nl_20210923.pem –-key mestanalyse.wur.nl.key -cacert 20220113_mestanalyse.wur.nl_onlyroots.cer -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @message-to-rvo.xml https://acceptatie.webservices.dictu.nl/labws/LabAnalyse
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: xn---cert-xu3b
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xn---cert-xu3b
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl_20210923.pem
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl_20210923.pem
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: xn---key-z86a
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xn---key-z86a
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl.key
* Closing connection 3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl.key
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: 20220113_mestanalyse.wur.nl_onlyroots.cer
* Closing connection 4
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 20220113_mestanalyse.wur.nl_onlyroots.cer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 145.12.137.54:443...
* Connected to acceptatie.webservices.dictu.nl (145.12.137.54) port 443 (#5)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [59 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [5589 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [621 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
{ [36 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
} [7 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [102 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
{ [2 bytes data]
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 5
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

Forced the handshake to be in TLS1.2:

```
kool035@L0154532 MINGW64 ~
$ curl --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 -v -k –-cert mestanalyse.wur.nl_20210923.pem –-key mestanalyse.wur.nl.key -cacert 20220113_mestanalyse.wur.nl_onlyroots.cer -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d @message-to-rvo.xml https://acceptatie.webservices.dictu.nl/labws/LabAnalyse
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: xn---cert-xu3b
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xn---cert-xu3b
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl_20210923.pem
* Closing connection 1
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl_20210923.pem
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: xn---key-z86a
* Closing connection 2
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: xn---key-z86a
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl.key
* Closing connection 3
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mestanalyse.wur.nl.key
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Could not resolve host: 20220113_mestanalyse.wur.nl_onlyroots.cer
* Closing connection 4
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 20220113_mestanalyse.wur.nl_onlyroots.cer
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 145.12.137.54:443...
* Connected to acceptatie.webservices.dictu.nl (145.12.137.54) port 443 (#5)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [247 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [59 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [5589 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
{ [621 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
{ [36 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
{ [4 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
} [7 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
} [102 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [16 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
{ [2 bytes data]
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 5
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

It seems like a different personal certificate is send to be send while mestanalyse.wur.nl should be used.

Comment: You can use `-v` option to see what is curl doing and why does the handshake fail.

Comment: Okay, I did that. I had to remove --trace-ascii logging since that overrides the -v option.

Comment: One weird thing I notice is that Client and Server hello is on TLS 1.3 but other messages are on TLS 1.2 - not sure if that's allowed/ok.

Comment: Hmm, okay. With adding --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 I can apparently force the hello to be also on TLS 1.2.

Comment: I found this link which seems to be similar to what you are facing: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192944.

Comment: I tried to force --sslv2 and --sslv3. I have version curl 7.80.0. I assume it is a problem with the certificate, that the wrong certificate is send.. But I have very litte knowledge about it. The government institute told me the SSL handshake fails and wrong certificate is send. Are these two different issues or is it just one that causes both to go wrong?

Comment: You may find this link useful: https://www.cloudflare.com/en-in/learning/ssl/what-happens-in-a-tls-handshake/. Also, yeah it seems server side is triggering handshake failure - maybe the certificate is not valid or the server side couldn't agree with the cipher spec, not sure really.

Comment: This helps me understand the handshake slightly better. Based on this I assume it will be a issue with the server certificate. I guess the wrong certificate is being send used by curl.

Comment: To conclude this post. We managed to get it working. Unfortunately not via Github. For some reason the certificate was not included in the message to the recipient. We managed to get it working via PowerShell using the certificate thumbprint.